# Postgres group by with order by does not return unique records

Tags: sorting, group-by, unique, distinct, postgresql-9.1

I am writing a query to get `unique school_id` order by latest `school id` from `school_images` table. Here is my query.

`select school_id, id from school_images group by id order by id desc`

Here is table structure -

```
id integer primary key
school_id integer
school_image varchar
```

Currently results are showing like below. those are not unique -

```
38705 
185 
185 
185 
22413 
3670 
3670 
24814 
22814 
17911 
16272 
18417 
17152 
24210
```

I am expecting results like -

```
38705 
185 
22413 
3670 
24814 
17911 
16272 
18417 
17152 
24210
```

Also I don't want to sort order by school_id. I want to sort either primary key or date like below -

```
select school_id, id 
from school_images group by id 
order by id desc 

select school_id, created 
from school_images 
group by id 
order by created desc
```

Both are giving duplicate records.

Comment: can you please also post the Actual and Expected result? So that we can help you better way.

Comment: you did group by `id` which is a primary key, and is always unique..

Comment: try this `select school_id from school_images group by school_id order by school_id desc`

Comment: Currently results are showing like below. those are not unique -
 
38705
185
185
185
22413
3670
3670
24814
22814
17911
16272
18417
17152
24210

I am expecting results like - 

38705
185
22413
3670
24814
17911
16272
18417
17152
24210

Also I don't want to sort order by school_id. I want to sort either primary key or I also have a date field with name crated any of them

Comment: I can use query only in two ways and both queries are giving duplicate records.
select school_id, id from school_images group by id order by id desc
or
select school_id, created from school_images group by id order by created desc

Comment: Please do not post additional information in comments. **Edit** your question and add the sample data and expected output as formatted text.

Comment: Your "expected" result can be obtained using: `select distinct school_id from school_images`

Comment: Yes, but I want to get latest school_id first so I am using order by and group by and because of this I have to add these fileds with select and then records got duplicate

Comment: `select distinct school_id from school_images order by school_id desc`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, it will work correctly

```
select school_id,id 
from school_images 
where CTID in (select max(CTID) from school_images group by school_id)
order by school_id
```

Here I have used CTID of rows, which are unique for each row in postgres sql.

Comment: `max(ctid)` will not give you the "latest" row